# Laravel - master view loads a view in index view but cannot load it in create view

Tags: laravel, view

I have a `layouts` folder under `views` folder where the `master.blade.php` is placed and I have `includes` folder under `views` folder where `nav.blade.php` is placed.

I have a `users` folder under `views` where `index.blade.php` and `create.blade.php` are placed.

[image]

Now i have extended the `master` view in both `index` and `create` views but the problem is that `index` page shows the navigation bar which is in `includes` folder and `create` page does not show it.

Master Page:
[image]

Index Page:
[image: Index File]

Create Page:
[image: Create Page]

I googled this but could not find any solution.

Comment: Can you post your blade files?

Comment: Can you post the Blade files or the Extends Statements of all the blade files???

Comment: Yeah, Both the index and create blade files are the same but the browser does not display navigation bar in create page.

Comment: Try copying everything to a blank laravel project. Or dump autoload and cache and try again?

Comment: I did, but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you post public repo?

Comment: what is public report?

Comment: Link to github repository

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani do you have any relational links to css files at your nav.blade and assets.blade? It may be just there, but invisible due to absence of some css files. May you attach what you get in browser's code inspector?

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest running `php artisan view:clear`. If the doesn't work would be able to show the the `Route`/Controller method for how your returning the `view`.

Comment: Thank you all, actually the css and js files were not loading properly, when I used URL::asset() method, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there are some issues in loading css and js files into the page.
To be sure to load them correctly don't write the path by hand but use the method:

```
URL:asset()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset